# Can the DENSO VS060 package run the DENSO VE026A arm?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My understanding is all DENSO arms run using B-Cap, on which the DENSO VS060 ROS package is based. If this is true, then will the DENSO VE026A (academic robot) run using the same ROS package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117346/can-the-denso-vs060-package-run-the-denso-ve026a-arm?/) by [mcross](https://answers.ros.org/users/10776/mcross/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

VS060 ROS packages uses slave mode of B-Cap, if VE026A runs with that mode, it should work. So please try them and if it does not work, please add comments at https://github.com/start-jsk/denso/issues/18

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2014-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mcross](https://answers.ros.org/users/10776/mcross/) on 2014-01-14**:
Thanks for the reply! The VE026A does run in slave mode, however it requires a serial connection rather than an Ethernet.